# How is IOTA´s transaction hash determined?

Tags: transaction, hashing, legacy-protocol

Ive been looking through documentation and articles but couldnt really find anything about it. I assume its the hash of all concatenated attributes? I am not talking about the bundle hash.

And a second question: How is the integrity of the references to the two tips  guaranteed? Is it because those references are included in the tx hash?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 1):

Yes and Yes :-)

It is simply the CURLP-81 of all the trytes in the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE 2021**

Please be aware that IOTA has changed at architectural level.

Read about it in the official documentation:
https://docs.iota.org/